# Counting included child blocks in the Neo plugin

Tags: loop, children, blocks, plugin-neo

In the [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo) plugin, I've made a block that has the option to add 3 child blocks underneath it.

This is the code from the parent block:

```
{% extends 'neo/default' %}
{% block blockContent %}

<section id="services" class="white-bg">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row margin-60">
     <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
       <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row margin-60">

    {% if block.children %}
     {% for item in block.children %}
     {% if loop.first %}
     {% include "neo/children/" ~ item.type %}
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

   </div>

 </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

So the parent block can have up to 3 child blocks. You'll get 3 blocks on one row, each block has a 'col-sm-4' (Up to 12 fit on one row if aren't familiar with Bootstrap) class so it fits on one row.

But if a user only chooses to have 2 child blocks the classes 'col-sm-4' will remain the same. I'd like to change this class to 'col-sm-6' and when only one child block is selected, 'col-sm-12'.

Okay so this is the code for the child block:

```
{% block blockContent %}    
{% for block in entry.body %}
{% switch block.type.handle %}
{% case 'serviceItem' %}

<div class="col-sm-4 margin-20 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
  <div class="text-center margin-20"><i class="fa {{ block.mainTitle }} fa-4x black"></i></div>
  {{ block.text }}
  <a class="more" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>

{% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What I tried first is set the length of the child block. And with that number defined, with the help of if statements, change the layout like this:

```
{% set numberOfItems = block.serviceItem|length %}
 {% if numberOfItems == 1 %}
  <div class="col-sm-12 margin-20 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
   <div class="text-center margin-20"><i class="fa {{ block.mainTitle }} fa-4x black"></i></div>
   {{ block.text }}
   <a class="more" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

 {% elseif numberOfItems == 2 %}

  <div class="col-sm-6 margin-20 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
   <div class="text-center margin-20"><i class="fa {{ block.mainTitle }} fa-4x black"></i></div>
   {{ block.text }}
   <a class="more" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
```

Etc...

Unfortunately that method doesn't work since it won't count itself more than once since it is being looped outside of the code file.

I hope my explanation was sufficient of what I hope to achieve.
Does anyone perhaps know the solution?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [Tom Bauer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/3535/tom-bauer) given to my question [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16999/5307) should be of help.

You're not far off. You need to set a variable and count the blocks in your neo loop. Then use if statements in the loop depending on the counter variable.

The other option is you add a columnWidth dropdown field, and give them the option to choose between 2 or 3, the values are the css (2=col-sm-6, 3=col-sm-4.)

Then your code code look like:

```
{% block blockContent %}    
{% for block in entry.body %}
{% switch block.type.handle %}
{% case 'serviceItem' %}

<div class="{{ block.columnWidth }} margin-20 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
  <div class="text-center margin-20"><i class="fa {{ block.mainTitle }} fa-4x black"></i></div>
  {{ block.text }}
  <a class="more" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>

{% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```